# Generic property of an algebraic (or analytic) morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In algebraic or analytic geometry, what do we mean by a generically étale morphism? or in general, what do we mean by a morphism satisfies a property generically?

P.S: I want to understand what is the difference between a finite morphism and a finite generically étale morphism between two algebraic (analytic) curves over a field (nonarchimedean field). I fined some definitions, but I was not sure whether it was the standard one.

Comment: By the way, your question appears to be attracting close votes. I think it's a very natural question to ask (sometimes it's an "everybody knows this" definition), but it may help ward off some of those close votes if you explain a bit about what lead you to ask this question and what difficulties you faced getting answers elsewhere. For more tips on this site's standards for questions, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a property $\mathcal{P}$ of a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is local on the source $X$, we say that $f$ is generically $\mathcal{P}$ when there is a dense open set $U\subset X$ so that $f|_U:U\to Y$ is $\mathcal{P}$. Since the property of being an etale morphism is local on the source (it's also local on the target), a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is generically etale iff there's a dense open subset $U\subset Y$ so that $f|_U:U\to Y$ is etale.

For properties of morphisms that aren't local on the source, definitions can differ. For instance, the property of being a finite morphism is *not* local on the source, so the definition of a generically finite morphism [looks a little different](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02NV).

Comment: Thanks! And by $\mathcal{P}$ local in the source, it just mean that If the morphism satisfies the property locally in the source then it satisfies the property, right?

Comment: A property $\mathcal{P}$ of $f:X\to Y$ is local on the source iff $f$ having $\mathcal{P}$ is equivalent to the statement "for every open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X$, $f|_{U_i}:U_i\to Y$ has $\mathcal{P}$ for all $i\in I$".